# Does the language defined in the details in NP-C or P?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, polynomial-time

It's known that:
$$
\textrm{CLIQUE} = \{(G,k): \mbox{G has a clique of size } k\}
$$
is $\textrm{NP-C}$, but what if every vertex has 2 neighbours (as defined in $\textrm{2d-CLIQUE}$)?
$$
\textrm{2d-CLIQUE} = \{(G,k): \mbox{every vertex in G has exactly $2$ neighbours and $G$ has a clique of size } k\}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that every vertex of $G$ has degree $2$, no clique of $G$ can have more than $3$ vertices. Then $\textrm{2d-CLIQUE}$ is trivially in $\textrm{P}$ and, if $\textrm{P} \neq \textrm{NP}$, it cannot be $\textrm{NP}$-complete.

Under the above assumption (which is trivial to check), $(G,k) \in \textrm{2d-CLIQUE}$ iff one of the following conditions holds:

- $k=0$, or
- $k \in \{1,2\}$ and $G$ is not empty, or
- $k = 3$ and $G$ has a triangle, which can be checked in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: ok, and what about 3d-CLIQUE?

Comment: For any constant $h \ge 0$, $h\textrm{d-CLIQUE}$ is in $\textrm{P}$.  If $k>h+1$ there can be no $k$-clique. If $k \le h+1$ you can then enumerate all the $O(n^k) = O(n^{h+1}) = n^{O(1)}$ subsets of $k$ vertices of $V$ and check in $O(h^2)$ time each if they induce a clique. In fact this even works for $\textrm{CLIQUE}$ if $k = O(1)$.